# Installing latest version of Zabbix agent

Tags: 12.04

I have 2 servers:

1. Staging server with Ubuntu 12.04
2. Production server with Ubuntu 12.04

I tried to install Zabbix agent on the above 2 servers, first I tried to install it on my production server using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install zabbix-agent
```

It's installing Zabbix 2.0.4 while the staging server installs Zabbix 1.8.11.

I want Zabbix **2.0.4** to be installed on my staging server too. I tried `sudo apt-get update` and everything but its not installing 2.0.4. How can I install the newer version?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `zabbix-agent 2.2.0` with [ppa:dottedmag/zabbix-agent](https://launchpad.net/~dottedmag/+archive/zabbix-agent) repository in 12.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dottedmag/zabbix-agent

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install zabbix
```

Comment: This ppa repository has not been updated since July 2014. The official Zabbix repos can be found at https://repo.zabbix.com/